# Changing make install directory on Ubuntu when building from source

Tags: ubuntu, make, source-code

I'm building the source from a package called OIS.

The package always installs in usr/local/include/OIS

I tried using the `./configure --includedir=/usr/local/include` flag but it seems that only changes the prefix not the suffix (OIS).

I could just copy the files but I'm not sure if this would break anything in the header files.

Can someone guide me where I could possibly edit so that when I run make install it would install in /usr/local/include and not /usr/local/include/OIS?

The reason I want to do this is because all the header files have "file.h" when in fact they're in "OIS/file.h". I would have to change this in all the header files so I want to change the install directory to avoid doing that, and in the future in case there's an update to the source.

Comment: Or you could just pass `-I` to the compiler like you're supposed to...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the -I flag. Could you show me a link to the documentation so I can read more about it?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options

Comment: Why don't you just install it from the repository?

Comment: But normally the `<package>-config` script or `<package>.pc` file should direct the compiler as to what flags it should use.

Comment: @Dennis Installing libois-dev from repository still installs it in /usr/include/OIS

Comment: @Ignacio, can you post your package comments as an answer? It was the closest to the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying a different directory to install under as you ask, use the `<package>-config` script or `<package>.pc` pkgconfig data file to get the appropriate flags to pass to the compiler.